# Translation question regarding 「ほどに」

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

I have a question regarding the translation of the following sentence.

人は誰もまた失うほどに求めるけど

I know the basic functions of ほど but still can't see how this plays out.

Comment: Do you have 2nd part of the sentence?

Comment: これの2番かと・・・　http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/204949/m0u/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AB/

Comment: @Shoko 回答したりーな。多分OPそれ読まれへんちゃう？

Comment: @l'électeur う～ん、でもそれくらい読めんかったら[こんな歌詞](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-75658.html)全部訳せへんやろし。。。あとさ、「誰もまた」の「また」 も難しいんちゃうかな～って思ってさあ。。[これ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/220116/m0u/)じゃなくて[これ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/208254/m0u/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F/)の①-2番やと思うねんけど、言うたげたほうがええんかなぁとか思て。。

Answer (score 6):

> 「Verb Phrase A + ほどに + Verb Phrase B」
>
> = "the more (Verb Phrase A), the more (Verb Phrase B)"

「[失]{うしな}うほどに[求]{もと}める」 ＝

「失うにつれて、ますます求める」 ＝

「失えば失うほど求める」, etc.

Thus, 「[人]{ひと}は[誰]{だれ}もまた失うほどに求めるけど」 means:

> "The more people lose, the more they desire, (but)...."